# When should I add a line break before an environment in LaTeX?

Tags: spacing, environments

When and with which environments should I use a line break in the code before the environment in LaTeX?

```
Here is the theorem we need:
\begin{theorem}
x^2+y = -xy
\end{theorem}
```

vs.

```
Here is the theorem we need:

\begin{theorem}
x^2+y = -xy
\end{theorem}
```

With the "enumerate"-environment the spacing before the environment seems to be the same but the general alignment of the page changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A blank line (which is I think what you are asking about here)  is an end of paragraph (it is reported to the tex macro layer as `\par`) so it is a question about the natural language content not a TeX question really. Just end a paragraph if you want the paragraph to end.

Some environments are "paragraph level" constructs and so always start a new paragraph, theorems for example, so it makes no difference whether you leave a blank line before or after a theorem enviornment as theorems are never within an paragraph.  Lists and display math however it does make a difference. If you end a paragraph before a list (such as `enumerate`) starts then (usually) the vertical spacing is different and (always) the text following the list environment is considered to be a new paragraph. Conversely if there is no paragraph break before the list, the list is considered to be part of the current paragraph (often part of the current sentence), and the following text is set as a continuation of the pararaph before the list.